# What should I use instead of the deprecated KeyboardEvent.which and KeyboardEvent.keyCode?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to strip jQuery out of an existing codebase as part of a modernization/optimization initiative. There are a few places where something needs to happen when a user hits the `enter` key while in a text input. Previously, we accomplished this with the following:

```
$("#loginInput").on("keypress", e => {
   if (e.which == 13) {
     // if key pressed was enter...
     login();
   }
});
```

However, reading through the keyboard event APIs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) I've found that most of the commonly used APIs are deprecated, such as `KeyboardEvent.which` and `KeyboardEvent.keyCode`.

Even though these properties are still available in most browsers, I feel uncomfortable using deprecated APIs. What should I use instead?

Comment: Is this unclear? "Warning: This attribute is deprecated; you should use KeyboardEvent.key instead, if available."

Comment: @str yes, at the time it was unclear. My brain for some reason didn't connect the dots between getting the result of KeyboarEvent.key and using the actual value of that instead of relying on the previous KeyboardEvent.which or KeyboardEvent.keyCode. After seeing e.which for so long I was expecting a numeric result. What's immediately clear to you might not be for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want `event.key`. It seems to be widely supported.

The "key" property gives the character reflected by the user interaction with the keyboard, taking into account all the meta keys involved (shift, ctrl, etc).

So to check for the carriage return character (13), you'd use

```
if (event.key === "Enter") {
  // enter key was pressed
}
```

*edit* updated to reflect the somewhat astonishing fact that the "key" property is set to the string "Enter" when that key triggers the event.

Comment: I think you need to check for `"Enter"` and not `"\n"`, [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values#Whitespace_keys). I attempted to add an edit to your post, but I think it got overwritten.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the answer, but no need to be uhh....snarky. If it was trivial I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @db2 ?? I was not trying to be snarky, I apologize for giving offense. I was unsure of what you meant.

Comment: event.key && event.key === "Enter" is redundant. If event.key is "Enter", then it is evidently truey. I think you wanted to write if (event && (event.key === "Enter"))

Comment: @LajosArpad that's a good point; the code was originally different when I was under the misimpression that `event.key` would be a Unicode character instead of the descriptive string. There was a call to `.charCodeAt()`.

Comment: @Pointy after the edit there is no longer any reason not to upvote this answer.